# What do these mean in prolog?

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

First when I read up on different predicates on Prolog, like for example `http_server`, it's written like this: `http_server(:Goal, +Options)` what does `:` and `+` mean here? Sometimes `?` is also written.
 Secondly sometimes I see variables declared with an underscore before them like `_Request`, even though there isn't any another `Request`, why is that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `+`, `-`, `:` etc. sigils are called *mode declarations*. They describe the expected instantiation of predicate arguments, i.e., whether you are expected to call the predicate with an unbound variable, an instantiated term, etc. These are not completely standardized; here is a description of the conventions for SWI-Prolog: http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=modes

As a first approximation, a `+` argument is an *input* to the predicate, you are supposed to provide a ground term. A `-` argument is an *output* of the predicate, the predicate will try to unify it with a term. A `?` term may be partially instantiated at the call, and the predicate may instantiate it further. A `:` argument is a meta-argument, i.e., it is a goal to be called by the predicate (as in `setof/3`, for example).

In the example of `http_server(:Goal, +Options)`, you are supposed to call this predicate with the first argument bound to a goal, probably a predicate name. The second argument must be instantiated, presumably to a list whose format is further described in the documentation. If you do *not* call this predicate like this, for example, if you pass an unbound variable as the second argument, you might get unexpected behavior or an instantiation error.

As for your second question (which would better have been separate), a variable that begins with an underscore is called an *anonymous variable*. Every such variable may only occur once per clause, except `_` itself, which may occur several times and refers to separate variables at each occurrence.

Prolog systems usually emit a "singleton variable" warning for non-anonymous variables that occur only once, because those might be typos or a sign the programmer forgot something. You use anonymous variables to express the notion that "there must be something here (e.g., a predicate argument), but I don't care what it is". In your example, presumably you call a predicate that has a "request" argument, but in your particular use case you don't care about the request.

Comment: Thanks, very nice explanation. Still there's one thing I don't understand, why call it `_Request` and not just `_`? Is it just for clarity that it is a request?

Comment: Yes, it's just to make the variable name more expressive.